# Reshape Encoder Decoder in Keras Model

Tags: python, keras

I have a simple machine translation model that converts English sentences to French sentences. I'd like to first pass in the model Encoder with the English sentences dimension. After being translated by Decoder, model outputs with the French sentences dimension. The problem here is English sentences and French sentences are of different lengths after padding. How do I do a reshape in between my Encoder and Decoder?

Here are my codes:

```
def encdec_model(input_shape, output_sequence_length, english_vocab_size, french_vocab_size):

    learning_rate = 1e-3

    input_seq = Input(input_shape[1:])
    encoder = GRU(64, return_sequences=True)(input_seq)
    decoder = GRU(64, return_sequences=True)(encoder)
    logits = TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size))(decoder)
    model = Model(input_seq, Activation('softmax')(logits))

    model.compile(loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer=Adam(learning_rate),
                metrics=['accuracy'])    

return model
```

The resultant model parameters look like:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
_________________________________________________________________
input_13 (InputLayer)        (None, 15, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_16 (GRU)                 (None, 15, 64)            12672     
_________________________________________________________________
gru_17 (GRU)                 (None, 15, 64)            24768     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_10 (TimeDis (None, 15, 344)           22360     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 15, 344)           0     
_________________________________________________________________
```

With an input dimension `(15,1)`, I'd like to change the output dimension to `(17,1)`

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This way, model may not be too good for translation. Becuase the decoder may not understand the logic between complete sentence. Better to encode the complete sentence in the compact form first and then use its cell states and encoded info for the decoder input.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ankish. Could you elaborate a bit more here? I thought by passing in the input_seq to encoder means the complete sentence. What would you suggest me to change here?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought by passing in the input_seq to encoder means the complete sentence.

You are passing complete sentence, what `GRU` will recieve one word at a time and it `roll-out` for the number of words in the sequence.

Let's take an example, your input is a sentence of something like `This is awesome platform, to share knowledge.` and its translation in `Hindi` language is `यह ज्ञान साझा करने के लिए बहुत बढ़िया मंच है।`. Now, here `last` word in `Hindi` is corresponding to the `2nd` word in `english`, and `last` word in `english` is corresponding to the `2nd` word in `english`(somehow) and etc.

My point here is that, as you send a `input` word to `encoder`, there will be some features correspond to it, which go to `decoder`, which have info about all the previous words. Now its output will be depend on only those words, which it has seen.

Also if any of the word in the sequence before the current step is wrong, that is obvious that complete sentence(of decoder) will be wrong, which it has not seen the complete sentence.

One option is encode the complete sequence to compact info, and then allow `decoder` to decode the info from `hidden-compact info`. [Here](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) is a well explained example to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. You are right, I think I need to rework on the model itself. It doesn't achieve the encoder-decoder implementation I require.